# Refactor C# code from inner foreach loop to outer foreach loop

Tags: c#, foreach

My code currently looks like like:

```
foreach(var request in requestsList){
    foreach(var myVar in request.anotherList){
       if(myVar.hasPermissions()) {
           //do something
       }
    }
}
```

`requestsList` is a `List` of `Request`s.
`myVar.hasPermissions()` requires a connection to the database so I want to minimize the number of calls to database. I want to move it outside of the inner `foreach` loop and make only one call per request.

I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
foreach(var request in requestsList){
    //check for permissions
    boolean perm = myVar.hasPermissions(); //database call to check permissions
    foreach(var myVar in request.anotherList){
       if(perm) {
           //do something
       }
    }
}
```

All I want to do is to move the `hasPermissions()` outside of inner `foreach` loop.
The problem I am facing is that I don't have access to `myVar` in the outer `foreach` loop. Both the loops iterating over lists is making it difficult for me.

Comment: `myVar` doesn't *exist* outside of the loop.  It's the variable that changes *with* the loop.  So presumably the results of `hasPermissions()` would *also* change.  Thus, it would need to be invoked again anyway.  If the results of that operation shouldn't change, then your modeling is incorrect.  Stop thinking about ways to trick the loop and start thinking about what your objects do and how they interact.  Semantically, what do these objects and operations *mean* to what this code is doing?

Comment: One has to assume that `hasPermissions` uses values from `myVar` which is why it is a method on the class. If so, you can't simply move it outside since there are multiple values being checked. What is the nature of `anotherList` and `myVar` and `hasPermissions`?

Comment: Moving outside of the loop is not a solution. In your code you have to access to database n times. I suggest to change the design of your function and make one single access to database (using request.anotherList as parameter, for example with a sql IN clause) and put the result in memory to use in the inner loop.

Comment: How many "myVar" do you end up checking?  Can this check be done simply with "myVar.Id" and "myVar.hasPermissions"?  If so, can you not go to the database once before either of these two loops and grab ALL myVar Ids and hasPermissions values?  Then you would just be comparing to a collection and not have to hit the database repeatedly.  You can also use this in caching if you need to check more than once and the "hasPermissions" value is not changed often.

Comment: You can't check the permissions before you iterate over the object. If you need to check all permissions on all list items in all requests, there isn't any more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If `hasPermission` is relatively static, i.e. you are certain that it wouldn't change across the runs of the outer loop, you could cache permissions as you check them:

```
IDictionary<MyVarType,bool> checked = new IDictionary<MyVarType,bool>();
foreach(var request in requestsList){
    foreach(var myVar in request.anotherList) {
        bool permitted;
        if (!checked.TryGetValue(myVar, out permitted)) {
            permitted = myVar.hasPermissions();
            checked.Add(myVar, permitted);
        }
        if(permitted) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

This way you would make exactly one call to `hasPermissions` per distinct instance of `myVar`; all subsequent checks would come from the `checked` cache.

Answer (score 0):

Without much more detail about your classes, we can only speculate how best to solve the problem. Assuming your `anotherList` consists of something like a list of users, you could cache the result of the check so you don't check again for the same user.

You can add a public field that uses `Lazy` to cache the result of calling `hasPermissions` - you have to initialize it in the constructors:

```
public class User {
    public bool hasPermissions() { // check database for permissions
        var ans = false; // ...
        return ans;
    }

    public Lazy<bool> cachedPermissions;

    public User() {
        UncachePermissions();
    }

    public void UncachePermissions() => cachedPermissions = new Lazy<bool>(() => hasPermissions());
}
```

Now you can access the `cachedPermissions` instead of calling `hasPermissions`:

```
foreach (var request in requestsList) {
    foreach (var myVar in request.anotherList) {
        if (myVar.cachedPermissions.Value) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

and `hasPermissions` will only be called once per `User` object. If it is possible that multiple `User` objects exist for a single database call, then more details on your classes and methods would be needed.

I added the `UncachePermissions` method to reset the cache as otherwise you could use really old values of `hasPermissions` which could cause issues. If that might be a common problem, you could cache outside the objects as part of the looping:

```
var permissionCache = new Dictionary<User, bool>();

foreach (var request in requestsList) {
    foreach (var myVar in request.anotherList) {
        bool permission;
        if (!permissionCache.TryGetValue(myVar, out permission)) {
            permission = myVar.hasPermissions();
            permissionCache.Add(myVar, permission);
        }
        if (permission) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are calling it the minimum number of times, in the top loop.

If you think about it another way...

```
//First get all the 'another' guys:
var allAnother = requestsList.SelectMany(anotherList => anotherList).ToList();

//If you don't have to check them all 
var permitGuys = allAnother.Distinct().Where(a => a.hasPermissions()).ToList();

//Do something with them
foreach(var permitGuy in permitGuys)
{
     //Do something
}
```

Comment: Unless you put in `Distinct` you aren't reducing the database calls.

Comment: This is not actually changing the behavior of the code, as the question is requesting.  (Well, technically you're creating multiple entirely unnecessary collections, consuming lots of memory for no benefit whatsoever, so it's more correct to say you haven't made any *beneficial* behavioral changes.)

Comment: Gah, I forgot the distinct

Comment: Now the code just doesn't even have the proper results, so it's performance characteristics are simply *irrelevant*.

Comment: ...You don't know that - we are making a lot of assumptions here - I was trying to highlight another way of thinking about the issue, by breaking it into smaller chunks

Comment: @DaveBish Why is highlighting a different way of thinking about the issue helpful when that different way produces the incorrect result, and doesn't address any of the problems being asked about?

Comment: Because if helps the questioner think about the issue, and what the looping is actually doing, in terms of it's effect on the data, and why his original attempt at re-writing his code was fundementally flawed. Additionally, it does produce the correct result, assuming Distinct() works - (we don't have enough information to know if it will, or wont).